# react-bootstrap-table missing module error upon startup

Tags: reactjs

When I try to run the client dev server, it bombs out with the following message:

```
Module not found:  Error:  Cannot resolve module 'react-dom/lib/getVendorPrefixEventName in: c:....ReactTransitionEvents.js
```

When I locate ReactTransitionEvents.js on my hard drive and look at it, I can see a require statement for getVendorPrefixEventName:

```
var getVendorPrefixedEventName = require('react-dom/lib/getVendorPrefixedEventName');
```

Is this looking for the lib folder in the react-dom folder in the main node_modules folder?

Comment: I think there might be version mismatch. Once check the compatabilities of `react`,  `react-dom` and `react-bootstrap-table`